# WordPress Admin Redirects to Previous EC2 Public DNS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I successfully installed WordPress 3.5.2 on my Amazon EC2 Amazon Linux AMI micro instance. I was able to log into the admin backend, and view my front end blog post.

However, after stopping and restarting the micro instance (in an effort to minimize the charges), I was given a new Public DNS address. I restarted the httpd and mysqld services. When I tried to access my admin backend with this new URL, I kept getting redirected to the previous Public DNS which no longer exists

```
http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/mysite/wp-admin
```

I cleared Chrome's cache. I could not find the site url among the configuration files. I'm not sure what to do. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WP-Admin will redirect to the `siteurl` option set in the `wp_options` table. This is generally the row with ID `1`, but you can get it with:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "siteurl";
```

You can update it with:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://your-new-site-name.com" WHERE option_name = "siteurl";
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. I logged into mysql as root, selected my WordPress database, and issued this command: `SELECT` * `FROM` wp_options `WHERE` option_name = "siteurl"; but I got a error 1146: Table 'mysite.wp_options' doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry, I forgot I changed the database prefix to something other than `wp`, I'm making progress now...

Comment: After updating it, I restarted the services httpd and mysqld. I'm able to access my front end (although there is no css styling). However, when I try to access the backend now, I'm getting this error: `404 Not Found. The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your Apache vhost with the new domain name?

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. I made a mistake by leaving out the subdirectory that WordPress is in. Your update statement worked by appending the directory to the end like this: `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://your-new-site-name.com/mysite" WHERE option_name = "siteurl"` Thank you so much!!!

Comment: i wish there was some healthier way to do this.. worked for me though, thanks.

Comment: further more, to make this answer more complete, see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

To make the accepted answer more complete, i suggest you all run the following mysql queries:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

and an altered version of the one given in the accepted answer:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the answer with more details. This will be helpful for people who are new to MySQL.
From the command window access root of MySQL.

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Then, choose the database you have already created(wordpress is my dbname):

```
use wordpress
```

Next, execute the command:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "siteurl";
```

Which will show what is in the table as given below.
[image]

Finally, modify the field with below command.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://your ip" WHERE option_name = "siteurl";
```

Comment: Brilliant! this should be voted as the clearest solution. Just tried it and works like a charm. Thank you!