# How to copy a WordPress site to a different domain

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog that I run, but I want to copy the entire blog to another "dummy" domain so I can make big changes on that domain, but have it not effect my main domain.

My main domain is http://www.startingtofeelit.com and my dummy domain is http://www.stfeelit.com

As you can see, they look almost identical, but I can't log in to the dummy domain as an admin to make some of the changes that I want to make. When I go to the login page on stfeelit.com, it automatically redirects me to startingtofeelit.com. I copied/pasted all the files from startingtofeelit.com to stfeelit.com, so there is probably a simple declaration of the "root folder" or something that points to startingtofeelit.com that I can change to stfeelit.com, but I don't know where this would be located.

As an example, try going to http://www.stfeelit.com/wp-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `siteurl` value in the `wp_options` table. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709721/wordpress-admin-redirects-to-previous-ec2-public-dns/17709901#17709901) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: Ahh yes. I had a feeling it would be something as simple as this, but I thought it would be a `define` statement somewhere in a PHP file. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

On your dummy page, you need to change the address to go to after logging in to be your dummy page and not your main page. You can do this by updating siteurl.