# Can't open Wordpress Admin on Ec2 Instance anymore

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I just configured and Ec2 Amazon Linux instance with wordpress and RDS. And them I logged on wp-admin, so far so good.

So I turned mu computer off and now when I put the ipv4 on my browser it goes directly to the site, also ok.

But If I type

`my_ipv4/wp-admin` or `myipv4/wp-login`

It does not work.

PS: when open the site, it open without the css layer.

Comment: If you ssh into the instance, and curl it from inside, does it work? Or maybe the issue only when accessing from the outside?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697007/wordpress-on-aws-ec2-broken-after-assigning-elastic-ip

Comment: @Marcin whats is curl? How can I do that?

Comment: Here’s a thought - have you allowed all the necessary ports through your instance security group for all IP addresses? If you have a port that you allowed only for your local IP, perhaps your IP has changed. I suspect that’s why you can access the site normally (port 80) but going to /wp-admin wants to enforce HTTPS (port 443) or some other port. I’m not at all experiences with WP though, so it’s just a hunch.

Comment: So, I had accessed mysql wp_users table and updated the user_url to the new URL, and now the wp-login.php open, still with no css, but when I insert the wordpress username and login, it gives me "it's no possible to reach the page"